# Force MPI program to run using only one process per node even if job script runs using several procs/node?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have a MPI program (Stream benchmark) which I need to run using 1 process per node even if I set for example 16 processes per node in my slurm job script. As I want only 1 process of a node use the entire memory of the node only on that MPI program.

I don't want to do any changes in my slurm job script. Since my stream-code is invoked in my other mpi-code so I have one executable file which includes two parts. I only want the part includes stream-code to be run on only one procs per node.

Shall I use some functions like memset? If so, how?
Is there any idea?

Comment: Hello, did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056961/running-slurm-script-with-multiple-nodes-launch-job-steps-with-1-task ? Does it answer your question ?

Comment: @francis Hi, thanks for your comment. It looks a nice way. But it doesn't work for my case since my stream-code is invoked in my other mpi-code so I have one executable file which includes two parts. I only want the part includes stream-code to be run on one procs/node. So I can only set something inside my stream-code.